# Next.js: Facebook pixel is not fired after router.push()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have some FB pixel code inside

```
<Script id="some-id" strategy="afterInteractive">some fb pixel code</Script>
```

The problem is when I navigate to page with script via  `router.push(SOME_ROUTE)`
the event is not fired. I've managed to fix this making `router.reload` and after that everything fires correctly, but gives not the best user experience because of reload.

Any explanation why FB Pixel not fires after `router.push`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NextJS router doesn't reload the page when navigating through pages... it works similar to a Single Page Application. You can read more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating) and [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#how-navigation-works)

You can find a full example on how to use Facebook pixel in [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-facebook-pixel) vercel repository